# Asp.net MVC3 How to use Model in javascript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

My Model is  Like this:

```
public class ViewMessageFileModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "FileOptionId")]
        public int ? FileOptionId { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "LeaveInMyInbox")]
        public bool ? LeaveInMyInbox { get; set; }



        IList<int> _fileforMyTeam;
        public IList<int> FileForMyTeam
        {
            get
            {
                if (_fileforMyTeam == null) _fileforMyTeam = new List<int>();
                return _fileforMyTeam;
            }
            set { this._fileforMyTeam = value; }
        }

         IList<int> _fileforfacility;
        public IList<int> FileForFacility
        {
            get
            {
                if (_fileforfacility == null) _fileforfacility = new List<int>();
                return _fileforfacility;
            }
            set { this._fileforfacility = value; }
        }
        //Similarly for other option   

        private IList<ViewUserGroupModel> _careTeam;
        public IList<ViewUserGroupModel> CareTeamForFile
        {
            get
            {
                if (_careTeam == null) _careTeam = new List<ViewUserGroupModel>();
                return _careTeam;
            }
            set { this._careTeam = value; }
        }

    }
```

I want to use this model in my view as follows

1-Use of care careteamforfile list directly in view iterating through @Model.CareTeamForFile
 .But I want to use Fileforfacility and fileformyteam List to store in a json variable in view based on the value of which i have to select or deselect some checkboxes

Is this possible for me to convert the Model element to json on view page.
Also suggest me the best approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CareTeamForFile))` to convert your list to JSON and return it as raw HTML. Then use `JSON.parse()` to convert it to a JavaScript object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CareTeamForFile))";

    var model = JSON.parse(json);

    ...
</script>
```

Comment: I have to convert json for Model.Fileforfacility in view  if I use the same model = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FileForFacility))"; alert(model[0])its not giving the int value saved in it

Comment: You need to parse the JSON before you use it, otherwise it's just a string var parsed = JSON.parse(model);

Answer (score 1):

Razor can parse the following just fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("@Model.CareTeamForFile ");
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: I want to get int value saved in List so what will be the syntax for that

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotation for use model in mvc Razor

For example :

```
$('#txtID').val('@Model.ID');
```